# how to set column names for groupby result

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a large df. With groupby on two columns, I have a value_counts on third column. So far so good:

```
df_group_chir = df_chir.groupby(['Spec','Year'])['type'].value_counts()
```

This gives the desired result:

```
                                        type
Spec          year       type
CHI          2017          D             876
                           K             639
             2018          D             893
                           K             524
             2019          D             969
                           K             567
```

Name: type, dtype: int64

But..... as you can see it says: Name: type. Nothing else. Following code shows 1 column as well:

```
df_group_chir.columns
Index(['type'], dtype='object')
```

First result is a Pandas series of course. Making this Series a DF, gives of course same result.

Knowing the following wouldn't work, but tried it anyway:

```
df_group_chir.columns=['Spec', 'Year', 'Type', 'Total']
```

Result:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 4 elements
```

My obvious question: how can I get (four) columnnames on the groupby result?

Thanks in advance!! greetings Jan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try `reset_index` with `name` option:

```
df_group_chir = df_chir.groupby(['Spec','Year'])['type'].value_counts()
df_group_chir = df_group_chir.reset_index(name='Total')
```

Comment: Hey Quang Hoang. Thanks. Unfortunally this gives an error: TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'. I changed the result of my df in my question. The word 'type' wasn't shown above the fourth column. Now it is in place above fourth column.

Comment: What version is your Pandas? `df_chir.groupby(['Spec','Year'])['type'].value_counts()` should give you just a series, not a dataframe. Unless you do: `df_chir.groupby(['Spec','Year'])[['type']].value_counts()`, note the double square brackets.

Comment: Quang Hoang goodmorning. It works with your code!! thanks. Pandas version is 1.0.5. I restarted the kernel and voila: perfect df with all columns named, thanks to your help. Thanks again and greetings Jan!!